# SQL Script to remove anchor tags in sql server

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008, sql-server-2008-r2, sql-server-2012

I have a small requirement. I need to remove the anchor tags only in a text (but not remaining HTML tags) but the text should not be removed.

Only anchor tag should be removed.

I got the below script and modified it a bit. It is working with one small issue i.e `</a>` is not getting removed. Can you please help me with this?

Please tell me if you have better idea.

Eg

```
<a href="google.com">Click to</a>
```

`Click to` should not get removed

Code:

```
CREATE FUNCTION [dbo].[udf_StripHTML] 
   (@HTMLText VARCHAR(MAX))
RETURNS 
   VARCHAR(MAX) 
AS
BEGIN
    DECLARE @Start INT
    DECLARE @End INT
    DECLARE @Length INT

    SET @Start = CHARINDEX('<a',@HTMLText)
    SET @End = CHARINDEX('>',@HTMLText,CHARINDEX('<',@HTMLText))
    SET @Length = (@End - @Start) + 1

    WHILE @Start > 0 AND @End > 0 AND @Length > 0
    BEGIN
        SET @HTMLText = STUFF(@HTMLText,@Start,@Length,'')
        SET @Start = CHARINDEX('<a',@HTMLText)
        SET @End = CHARINDEX('>',@HTMLText,CHARINDEX('<',@HTMLText))
        SET @Length = (@End - @Start) + 1
    END

    RETURN LTRIM(RTRIM(@HTMLText))
END
GO
```

Comment: Why not just replace `RETURN LTRIM(RTRIM(REPLACE(@HTMLText, '</a>', ''))`?

Answer (score 1):

try this.

[Fiddle Demo Here](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!6/dbf6c/6)

```
declare @HTMLText varchar(max)='<a href=''hello.com''>click me</a>'

DECLARE @Start INT
DECLARE @End INT
DECLARE @Length INT
SET @Start = CHARINDEX('<',@HTMLText)
SET @End = CHARINDEX('>',@HTMLText,CHARINDEX('<',@HTMLText))
SET @Length = (@End - @Start) + 1
WHILE @Start > 0 AND @End > 0 AND @Length > 0
BEGIN
SET @HTMLText = STUFF(@HTMLText,@Start,@Length,'')
SET @Start = CHARINDEX('<',@HTMLText)
SET @End = CHARINDEX('>',@HTMLText,CHARINDEX('<',@HTMLText))
SET @Length = (@End - @Start) + 1
End
select LTRIM(RTRIM(@HTMLText))
```

**EDIT:2** *Only To Remove Anchor Tags*`<a href="hello.com">` and `</a>`
[Fiddle Demo](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!6/dbf6c/17)

```
declare @HTMLText varchar(max)='<l href=''fvhjfshdfsd''>gsgdgfsdf</l><a href=''hello.com''>click me</a><b>aa</b>'

DECLARE @Start INT
DECLARE @End INT
DECLARE @Length INT


SET @Start = CHARINDEX('<a',@HTMLText)


SET @End =CHARINDEX('>',@HTMLText,CHARINDEX('<a',@HTMLText))
SET @Length = (@End - @Start) + 1
WHILE @Start > 0 AND @End > 0 AND @Length > 0
BEGIN
SET @HTMLText = STUFF(@HTMLText,@Start,@Length,'')
SET @Start = CHARINDEX('<a',@HTMLText)
SET @End = CHARINDEX('>',@HTMLText,CHARINDEX('<a',@HTMLText))
SET @Length = (@End - @Start) + 1
End
select REPLACE(LTRIM(RTRIM(@HTMLText)),'</a>','')
```

Comment: The Above code removes all the html tags in the text <B> Hello User </B> <a href=''hello.com''>click me</a> Output: Hello User Click me

Comment: yes, it'll remove all tag, let me update my answer ,wait a sec@user3330998

Comment: See my EDIT 2 Answer now, hope it'll help. :) @user3330998

Comment: Excellent.  I've turned both of these into SQL functions.  :)