# How to remove an anchor tag from body, if matched with the given matching URL in SQL

Tags: sql, sql-server, url, anchor, href

I have a `sample input body` below, which contains `anchor tag` -

```
<p>I personally use a <a href="http://www.prevention.com/fitness/6-must-have-mobility-tools">massage stick</a> on a regular basis, and highly recommend one called the Tiger Tail, which retails for less than $30. I keep it by my bedside to address the exercise-related leg cramps I occasionally experience during the night. Since the cramps I generally get attack my smaller muscles, making them difficult to treat with regular stretching, I use the Tiger Tail instead. After a few minutes of rolling over the cramping muscle, the pain typically disappears or at least has been significantly reduced.</p>
```

Now, if the below given `URL` contains in the above `body`, then the `whole anchor tag` should be `removed` `(excluding wrapped text)`-

```
http://www.prevention.com/fitness/6-must-have-mobility-tools
```

**Expected Output of body-**

```
<p>I personally use a massage stick on a regular basis, and highly recommend one called the Tiger Tail, which retails for less than $30. I keep it by my bedside to address the exercise-related leg cramps I occasionally experience during the night. Since the cramps I generally get attack my smaller muscles, making them difficult to treat with regular stretching, I use the Tiger Tail instead. After a few minutes of rolling over the cramping muscle, the pain typically disappears or at least has been significantly reduced.</p>
```

**Note -** The solution should be `generic and dynamic` with `no static data`.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Will the open anchor tag always be exactly this string? `<a href="http://www.prevention.com/fitness/6-must-have-mobility-tools">` or might it have extra spaces or other HTML attributes applied - making a simple dumb string match unviable.

Comment: @MartinSmith - anchor tag starts with the exactly the same string, and yes by mistake i replied with the other account. Sorry for that.

Answer (score 0):

If your text will be static as above, then this will be helpful.
Suppose @T is your target string & @S is your search string

```
SELECT REPLACE(REPLACE(@T,@S, ''), '<a href="">massage stick</a>', 'massage stick') AS A;
```

Answer (score 0):

As XML:

```
Declare @v As XML = '<p>I personally use a <a href="http://www.prevention.com/fitness/6-must-have-mobility-tools">massage stick</a> on a regular basis, and highly recommend one called the Tiger Tail, which retails for less than $30. I keep it by my bedside to address the exercise-related leg cramps I occasionally experience during the night. Since the cramps I generally get attack my smaller muscles, making them difficult to treat with regular stretching, I use the Tiger Tail instead. After a few minutes of rolling over the cramping muscle, the pain typically disappears or at least has been significantly reduced.</p>'

Select 
       '<p>' + y.value('(.)[1]', 'VARCHAR(5000)') + '</p>' As Result
From   
       @v.nodes('/p') As x(y)
```

Answer (score 0):

I created this SQL function for the purpose described:

```
create or alter function [dbo].[TMFN_RmAnchorLinksNotText](@HTMLText nvarchar(max))
returns nvarchar(max)
as
begin

    DECLARE @Start INT
    DECLARE @End INT
    DECLARE @Length INT

    SET @Start = CHARINDEX('<a',@HTMLText)
    SET @End =CHARINDEX('>',@HTMLText,CHARINDEX('<a',@HTMLText))
    SET @Length = (@End - @Start) + 1

    -- Remove all anchor start-tags, inc. href='xxx'.
    WHILE @Start > 0 AND @End > 0 AND @Length > 0
    BEGIN
        SET @HTMLText = STUFF(@HTMLText,@Start,@Length,'')
        SET @Start = CHARINDEX('<a',@HTMLText)
        SET @End = CHARINDEX('>',@HTMLText,CHARINDEX('<a',@HTMLText))
        SET @Length = (@End - @Start) + 1
    END

    -- Remove all anchor end-tags:
    SET @HTMLText = REPLACE(LTRIM(RTRIM(@HTMLText)),'</a>','')


    return @HTMLText
end
```

Ref. [SQL Script to remove anchor tags in sql server](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29193038/sql-script-to-remove-anchor-tags-in-sql-server)
;)